# why hidden div is not staying after button click in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

i am trying to show a hidden div after a login button click event..but the div is not staying..it is vanishing after the login click..but i want to stay the div after login button click and it will stay in the page untill i click anything in the page..

my button

```
<asp:Button ID="loginbutton" runat="server" Text="Login"  OnClientClick=" return someFunction();"/>
```

my javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function someFunction() {
    $("#logdiv").show();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the div is not stay visible after the click of your button **because you make at the same time post back**, after the reload of the page the div is hidden again.

I am not suggest you to hold the post back because probably is not what you want. You can try either render the div again with visible on, either register some other script after the post back to make it visible.